# Unumbered chapter causing 0.X.X section

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have the following macro

```
\newcommand{\softChapter}[1]{

    %Create chapter
    \chapter*{#1}

    %Add it to TOC
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}

    %Reset section counter, to avoid precedent section
    %from interfering
    \setcounter {section} {0}
}
```

I do want it have to do, an unumbered chapter, expect for one thing. The sections under i start, with 0, so my section are 0.X.X. I want my section to be. X.X

Comment: Wouldn't that be confusing since they would appear to be from different chapters?

Comment: I agree but it's to match an assignment requirements. Beside it's more like there is two document merged in the same PDF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package to change the dependence between the chapter and section counters.

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

This will have the desired effect.