# Setting sub-section when section is not numbererd

Tags: sectioning, numbering

My code looks something like:

```
\section*{Perspectives}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\subsection{...}
```

The problem is that the subsection now starts from 0.2 instead of 0.1 initially, whereas I want it to start from 1.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the same problem from [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14076/unumbered-chapter-causing-0-x-x-section).

Comment: fixed a typo: the counter is `subsection` and not `\subsection`.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question; you want an unnumbered section, but its subsections must be numbered 1.0, 1.1, 1.2,... where the leftmost digit (1 in my example) comes from the (unnumbered) section and the rightmost digit comes from the corresponding subsection?

Comment: @Mike: Such hints should be added as comments. I took the liberty to convert it to one. Note that you can simply copy and paste question or answer links into a question or answer (but not into comments) and it is automatically formated to show the post title. This looks much better than "here" or "this X" links.

Answer (score 3):

sectioning commands advance their own counter. So if you want the numbering of your subsections to start with 1 you must initialize the number to 0: `\setcounter{subsection}{0}`.

If you want to change the printed output from  "0.1" (which is `\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}`) to something else, redefine `\thesubsection`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\let\Oldthesubsection\thesubsection
\section*{Perspectives}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\subsection{...}
...
\let\thesubsection\Oldthesubsection
\section{A numbered new one}
...
```